# Why is this slice giving gaps in Outlook Web?

Tags: html, html-email

I am getting gaps with this image signature I am trying to use, could you please help me?

Any help would be great!

I've already tried align:left and margin:0, in Gmail the signature is fine but on Outlook it won't work

https://codepen.io/piefun/pen/pBLPbV

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    td {line-height:0; font-size: 0.0em; }
    img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
</style>
</head>


<html>
<head>
<title>PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi.jpg) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="600" height="60" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <a href="http://pwauk.co.uk/"> <img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_01.gif" width="158.40" height="60" alt=""></td></a>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_02.gif" style="margin-right:-1px" width="259.20" height="36.96" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <a href="mailto:dw@pwauk.co.uk"><img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_03.gif" width="128.16" height="20.64" alt=""></a></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/dominicwaters/"><img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_04.png" style="margin-left:-1px" width="54.24" height="36.96" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://pwauk.co.uk/"><img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_05.gif" style="margin-left:-0.5px" width="128.16" height="16.32" alt=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="http://www.nathancole.me/signatures/pwa/PWA_Email_Signature_Dominic_Waters_300dpi_06.gif" width="441.45" height="23.04" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
</html>
```